# `focusable()` broken for views that are not already focusable

Tags: swiftui

This is taken from a completely fresh multiplatform SwiftUI project. I want to be able to make a custom view focusable, so I tried testing with a `Text` view but it's not working. Isn't that the whole point of `.focusable()` to declare an arbitrary view focusable? If that's the case, then why isn't it working in the below code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @FocusState private var focusedItem: Optional<FocusedItem>

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Test")
                .focusable(true)
                .focused($focusedItem, equals: .two)

            Button("Toggle Focus") {
                self.focusedItem=(self.focusedItem == nil) ? .two : nil
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
                      
                    // Always prints `nil`.
                    print(self.focusedItem)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    enum FocusedItem {
        case one, two
        func other() -> FocusedItem {
            switch self {
            case .one: return .two
            case .two: return .one
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```